# Track light to Empty - with ability to rotate Light or Empty

Tags: tracking

I would like to point a Sun Light to the World Center.
**Track To** with **-Z & Y up** does the job nicely... but I would need to rotate the sun around Z and also around Y. (Azimuth/Elevation)

If I track the Light to the Empty, I'm no longer able to rotate the Sun.
I thought if I rotate the Empty, the sun might follow but that's not the case.

How can I aim the sun to the Empty but still be able to manipulate it's position by two rotation values? (I'm using the setup in an Add-on, therefore the rotation.)
Thanks for any Help.

Answer (score 1):

You can parent Sun Light to the Empty so that the Empty will rotate it. To do that, select Sun Lamp than Empty with holding <kbd>Shift</kbd>, and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>

Start like this:

[image]

And track to is not necessary for this setup

To change Elevation press <kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>X</kbd> (rotate in local X):

[image]

Azimuth  <kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Z</kbd> (Global Z)

I'm not sure about that add-on you are using, but a built-in "Sun position" add-on already directs the sun in center:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. I have not thought of parenting... but it makes sense. You still need to Track the Light to the Empty though because the sun light also need a direction from which it shines. Parenting only will retain the light ray direction regardless of the rotation by the Empty. Combining the two (parenting and also Tracking to the Empty) solves the problem perfectly. Fantastic. Thanks! (I write an Add-on myself where I need this setup.)